# Можно ли как-то сохранять прочитанные вопросы кроме как звездочкой?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

Хочется сохранять проанализированные вопросы, делать по ним поиск и тому подобное.

Есть ли какой-либо встроенный функционал для этого?

Comment: А чем вам звёздочка не нравится? )

Comment: Ей хочется метить любимые вопросы, а не все подряд 

Comment: Нету, используйте внешние каталогизаторы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кастомизированных списков вопросов (по их идентификатору), кроме как помещение их в список избранных, не предусмотрено. Однако, учитывая, что вся активность участника фиксируется, за интересные вопросы можно голосовать и после этого получить их список в соответствующем [разделе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote) профиля. Дополнительно стоит заметить, что у этого способа есть одно преимущество перед избранными вопросами - такой список не виден другим участникам, так как голоса на сообщениях анонимны. Только модераторы могут видеть ваши голосования и то с  ограничением на свои собственные сообщения. В то время как список избранных вопросов любого участника доступен в его профиле для всех.